# Ternary operator within a Django query not working

Tags: python-3.x, django

Am tring to use a ternary operator in a django custom query but it throws an exception, below is my sample code :

```
    def update_cp_generic(self,  customer_profile, defaults, data):
    """
    Update customer profile generic function for Person and Business.

    :param customer_profile: CustomerProfile object.
    :param defaults: dict, params for Person and Business.
    :param data: This is dict for configurations of Business and Person

    :return: The instance of the updated customer profile.
    """
    new_roles = defaults.pop('roles')
    key = 'person' if data['type'] is 'Person' else 'business'
    cp_entity = data['entity'].get_or_create(
        customer_profile=customer_profile,
        **{key: self}
    )
    for attr, value in defaults.items():
        setattr(cp_entity, attr, value)
    deleting_roles = list(set(cp_entity.roles) - set(new_roles))
    self.delete_roles(deleting_roles, customer_profile, cp_entity)
    if cp_entity.id:
        cp_entity.roles = new_roles
        cp_entity.save()
    return self
```

This is the error thrown :

```
TypeError: get_or_create() got an unexpected keyword argument 'person'
```

am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can try it with this ?

```
cp_entity = data['entity'].get_or_create(**{"customer_profile", customer_profile, key: self})
```

And if you still getting same error then here you are trying to add `person` field that is not present in your model.

Answer (score 1):

The 'is' keyword is wrong here!

It should be.

`key = 'person' if data['type'] == 'Person' else 'business'`